# Accessing matched substrings when substituting using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match two regular expressions A and B where A and B appear as 'AB'. I want to then insert a space between A and B so that it becomes 'A B'.

For example, if A = [0-9] and B = !+, I want to do something like the following.

```
match = re.sub('[0-9]!+', '[0-9] !+', input_string)
```

But, this obviously does not work as this will replace any matches with a string '[0-9] !+'.

How do I do this in regular expressions (preferably in one line)? Or does this require several tedious steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the groups!

```
match = re.sub('([0-9])(!+)', r'\1 \2', input_string);
```

`\1` and `\2` indicate the first and second parenthesised fragment. The prefix `r` is used to keep the `\` character intact.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the input string is `"I have 5G network"` but you want whitespace between `5` and `G` i.e. whenever there are expressions like `G20` or `AK47`, you want to separate the digit and the alphabets (`I have 5 G network`). In this case, you need to replace a regex expression with another regular expression. Something like this:

`re.sub(r'\w\d',r'\w \d',input_string)`

But this won't work as the substituting string will not retain the string caught by the first regular expression.

**Solution:**

It can be [easily solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763772/2374691) by accessing the groups in the regex substitution. This method will work well if you want to add something to the spotted groups.

`re.sub(r"(\..*$)",r"_BACK\1","my_file.jpg")` and `re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'<num>\1</num>',"I have 25 cents")`

You can use this method to solve your question as well by capturing two groups instead of one.

`re.sub(r"([A-Z])(\d)",r"\1 \2",input_string)`

Another way to do it, is by [using lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312719/2374691):

`re.sub(r"(\w\d)",lambda d: d.group(0)[0]+' '+d.group(0)[1],input_string)`

And another way of doing it is by using look-aheads:

`re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)",r" ",input_string)`