# Regular expression to match everything after two words

Tags: python, regex, lambda

I've been trying to use regular expressions to remove a part of a string.

```
Heroes Chapter 91 - Rescue
```

I need to remove everything after "Chapter -number-", I can't remove everything after "-" because I'm not sure if the title is always gonna be "Heroes" so, if the title is "-New- Spiderman", it'll remove the wrong part. Same goes with the "-", if it removes everything after a "-", it might remove the wrong part. It has to be "Chapter -number-". I don't know if I explained it well.

However, I've tried doing it like this:

```
title = "Heroes Chapter 91 - Rescue"
title = re.sub('Chapter \d+ (\D+)', '', title)
```

but it returns `Heroes`.

```
title = "Heroes Chapter 91 - Rescue"
title = re.sub('Chapter (\d+).*', '', title)
```

but it returns `Heroes`, again.

Any ideas?

PD: Someone linked me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763750/how-to-replace-only-part-of-the-match-with-python-re-sub) but I can't find the solution there, if someone sees it, please point it out. I'm clearly not an expert :)

Final solution:

```
title = "Heroes Chapter 91 - Rescue"
title = re.sub('(Chapter \d+).*', '\\1', title)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group `( )` here and reference the captured group in your replacement.

```
>>> re.sub('(Chapter \d+).*', '\\1', title)
'Heroes Chapter 91'
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will. `re.sub` REPLACES the matched part in the whole string. The matched part is "Chapter 91 - Rescue" since it completely matches the pattern 'Chapter (\d+) (\D+)', and then you replace it entirely with '', so it's removed. The only unmatched part is 'Heroes'.

You can match everything again but instead of returning '' you could return a part of the matched string:

```
re.sub('(Chapter \d+).*', '\\1', title)
```

with that, you're keeping only the subpattern between parens, discarding the rest. you'd be keeping "Heroes Chapter 91" with that pattern, where 'Heroes ' was not matched but 'Chapter 91 - Rescue' was, ending with a .* (greedy star operator matching 'till the end of the any-nonline-character list) for the part after the chap. number. From that match, only 'Chapter 91' is kept because it matches the first subpattern (the only one in parens), and only that subpattern is get and replaced the original part. That's how you keep 'Heroes ' + 'Chapter 91' (discarding the trailing part - the actual title)

Comment: I know. Read again please.

Comment: Read again both the question AND the answer. He wants to keep "Heores Chapter 91" discarding the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tested it and it returns "Heroes" for some reason. Same happens with cheshicat's answer, unless I'm doing something wrong.                                                   >>> title = "Heroes Chapter 91 - Rescue"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(Chapter \d+).*', '\1', title)
'Heroes \x01'

Comment: debug your string before and after the regex-matching (i.e. use breakpoint or a plain-old print in console)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
title = re.sub('(Chapter \d+) .*', '\1', title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a *lookbehind*:

```
re.sub('(?<=Chapter \d+) - .*', '', title)
```

If re doesn't support quantifiers in the lookbehind, go with cheshircat's solution.

Comment: It returns an error, I guess it doesn't support it :(

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't support the quantifiers.