# convert polynomial to list type

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to convert a polynomial

for example

```
2x^2
```

and turn it into a list

```
[2,0,0]
```

where it can be used for the numpy poly1d function

here is my current code

```
def convert_poly_to_list_type(poly):
    # sort list and split
    poly = sorted(str(poly).split())
    poly1 = []
    for i in poly:
        if i == "+":
            pass
        else:
            poly1.append(i)
    # take out "+"
    exponents = []
    for i in poly1:
        x = i.split("^")
        if len(x) == 1:
            exponents.append(0)
        else:
            print(x)
            exponents.append(int(x[1]))
    # find largest exponent
    integers_in_list = int(max(exponents)) + 1
    numpy_list = [0] * integers_in_list
    # create a list
    for i in poly1:
        i = i.split("^")
        if len(i) == 1:
            numpy_list[len(numpy_list) - 1] += int(i[0])
        else:
            z = i[0]
            z = int(z[:len(z) - 1])
            y = int(i[1])
            numpy_list[len(numpy_list) - 1 - y] += z
    return numpy_list
```

but it gets the error:

```
z = int(z[:len(z) - 1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can someone please give me some code to fix this?  I have searched for 2 hours now and haven't found a solution

Comment: Hey, does the format match exactly `nx^k` all the time? Asking because you can simplify your function.

Comment: No it can also be nx^k + nx^k - n @Zeromika

Comment: Could you please provide _exact_ expected format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces your error:

```
In [31]: int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-31-e4f84bb32d50>", line 1, in <module>
    int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So

```
z[:len(z) - 1]
```

must be producing an empty string `''`.  And `z` must then either be '' or '1' (one character).

Code like this needs some debugging `print` statements while tracking down problems.  There's nothing mysterious about that; you just have to be careful and pay attention to the details!

Comment: When I print z out it is an integer and not an empty string.  Can you help me debug it?  I haven't found a fix to it

Answer (score 0):

One can almost get `sympy` to do all the work, including grouping the like terms. Annoyingly, we need to do some string manipulation to get from `"2x^2"` to `"2*x^2"`. Maybe there is a better way.

```
from sympy import sympify, Poly, var
import re

s = "2x^2 + 7x^2 + 11x - 20"
# see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763750/how-to-replace-only-part-of-the-match-with-python-re-sub
s2 = re.sub(r"(\d)([a-z])", r"\1*\2", s)

# define a variable x
x = var("x")
# construct a sympy polynomial from string
# WARNING: this may call eval
expr = Poly(sympify(s2), x)
# get the coefficients
coefs = expr.coeffs()
print(coefs)
# [9, 11, -20]
```