# How to replace the last occurrence of a part of a search string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string and want to replace the last comma with an "&". I want to do it with Regex, also if it could be done without Regex.
This is my example code.

```
mystring = "a, b, c, d"
print(re.sub(r", \w$", " & ", mystring))  # this gives me "a, b, c &"
                                          # but I want    "a, b, c & d"
```

Please: Before you press "close" write a comment! There is no duplicate and this should also be reproducible. See the code comments!

Comment: Does it have to be regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/rreplace-how-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-an-expression-in-a-string?

Comment: @Guy yes!  Therefore I added a tag.

Comment: `"".join(mystring[::-1].replace(",", "& ", 1)[::-1])` just in case you need a solution without `regex` :)

Comment: Of course there are duplicates of this, a lot. Here is one, [How to replace only part of the match with python re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763750/how-to-replace-only-part-of-the-match-with-python-re-sub), canonical.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hello Wiktor, but there I don't know how to take the last occurrence. But you said a lot. I don't think there is one with last-occurence.

Comment: There is no problem with your pattern, you just need to capture and backreference the captured text. A common, very well-known issue.

Comment: You may as well find `,(?!.*,)` and replace with `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a group `()` and a backreference `\1`.

```
>>> mystring = "a, b, c, d"
>>> print(re.sub(r", (\w)$", r" & \1", mystring))
a, b, c & d
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)